# Redirect to the previous page using session history/management using nodejs/react/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import createMemoryHistory from 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory';
import { ArrowButton } from '../../components';

const history = createMemoryHistory();
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
});
history.push('/home', { some: 'state' });
createMemoryHistory({
  initialEntries: ['/'],  // The initial URLs in the history stack
  initialIndex: 0,          // The starting index in the history stack
  keyLength: 6,             // The length of location.key
  // A function to use to confirm navigation with the user. Required
  // if you return string prompts from transition hooks (see below)
  getUserConfirmation: null,
});
history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(`The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`);
  console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`);
});
const genericMessage = 'We have a problem.';

const RegistrationError = ({
  reason,
  returnToUrl,
  goBack,
}) => (
  <div className="registration-error">
    <h2 className="register-title">Sorry!</h2>
    <p>{ reason || genericMessage }</p>
    { !reason && (
      <ArrowButton
        onClick={() => returnToUrl(history.go(-1))}
      >
        Close
      </ArrowButton>
```

I am new to Nodejs, and having difficulties understanding some concept. The problem that I have is when I click on the Close button, the page should redirect to the previously viewed site. However this is not working. What am i doing wrong? If anyone could point me to the right direction. I have checked similar problems on stack overflow, which did not help me.

Comment: Does `RegistrationError` actually receive all the props it needs?

Comment: yes it does: RegistrationError.propTypes = {
  reason: PropTypes.string,
  returnToUrl: PropTypes.func,
  goBack: PropTypes.func,
};